# Asymptotic limit of truncated Legendre sieve

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Consider the truncated sum

$$
S(x):=\sum_{\substack{{d\mid P(\sqrt{x})}\\{d\leq x}}}\mu(d)/d,
$$

where $P(z)$ is the product of all primes less than or equal to $z$, and $\mu(d)$ is the Möbius function.

My question is simply:

> Does $S(x)$ have a provable asymptotic limit?

The question is motivated by the following plot:
[image: Plot of truncated Euler product]

It is well known from the prime number theorem and Merten's product theorem that 
$$
\frac{x}{\log x \cdot \pi(x)} \sim 1 \quad \textrm{and} \quad
\log x \cdot \sum_{\substack{{d\mid P(\sqrt{x})}}}\mu(d)/d \sim 2 \textrm{e}^{-\gamma}. 
$$
And in seeing the plot, I got curious of
$$
\log x \cdot S(x) \sim ?
$$
It is not possible to state from the numerical example what the asymptotic limit of $\log x \cdot S(x)$ will be. But note that so is the case also of $x/(\log x \cdot \pi(x))$, which provable tends to 1. What I'm curious about therefore, is whether $\log x \cdot S(x)$ will go all the way to 1 or stagnate before that.

I did check out chapter 4 of Opera de Cribro by Friedlander and Iwaniec. There it appears that at least in terms of the elementary Legendre sieve, it is not possible to prove the asymptotic limit of $S(x)$. It might be that an affirmative answer lies other places in that book, with more powerful sieving methods. I would be glad if anyone could point me to the right place in that case, as it is a rather chunky piece of literature to just browse through.

**ADDED 1:** Numerically, it appears that the constant $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M(k) \log \Big(1+\frac 1k\Big)$ that was stated below in Lucia's answer should be 1, as according to Terry Tao's comment. This is evidenced in the following plot:
[image: convergence to 1 of Lucia's sum]

**ADDED 2:** One could also anticipate the asymptotic limit 
$$
S(x)\sim 
\frac{1}{\log x}
$$
from the following sloppy heuristic: $S(x)$ can in some sense be seen as the mean value of prime densities below $x$. If we take those densities to be $1/\log x$ around $x$, the average density is simply $\textrm{li}(x)/x$. We know of course that this expression satisfies 
$$
\frac{\textrm{li}(x)}{x} \sim \frac{1}{\log x}.
$$
We might therefore anticipate $S(x)\sim 1/ \log x$. I have added a new version below of the first plot, that also includes the term $\log x \cdot \textrm{li}(x)/x$, revealing that this lies above $\log x \cdot S(x)$. Naturally, we would not expect the two to coincide, as $S(x)$ must interpreted as the mean of a random model where the actual prime distribution is just one specific outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One can prove that $(\log x)S(x)$ does tend to a limit, but I don't think the limit is necessarily a nice constant. [**Edit** The limit is in fact $1$ as noted by Terry Tao and user45947. ] Put $M(z) = \sum_{n\le z} \mu(n)/n$.  Note that by the prime number theorem $M(z) \ll (\log z)^{-A}$ for any $A>0$ and $z$ large enough.  I'll prove that 
$$ 
S(x) \sim \frac{1}{\log x} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} M(k) \log \Big(1+\frac 1k\Big),
$$ 
and the bound on $M(k)$ guarantees that the sum above is convergent.  This constant can of course be computed (and should be checked with your numerics) but I don't see why it should be anything nice. [ **Edit** In fact one can see that 
$$ 
\sum_{k=1}^{K} M(k) \log \Big( 1+ \frac 1k \Big) = \sum_{n\le K} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}\sum_{k=n}^{K}\log (1+1/k) = \sum_{n\le K} \frac{\mu(n)}{n} \log \frac{K+1}{n}.
$$ 
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{K} \mu(n)/n = O((\log K)^{-A})$ and $-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(n)(\log n)/n=1$, it follows that the constant is in fact $1$. ]

To prove the asymptotic formula, note that $S(x)$ counts all $n\le x$ except for those $n$ having a prime factor $p$ larger than $\sqrt{x}$.  Thus 
$$ 
S(x) = M(x) - \sum_{p>\sqrt{x}} \sum_{\substack{n\le x \\ p|n }} \frac{\mu(n)}{n}.  
$$
The term $M(x) = O(1/(\log x)^2)$ and so we focus just on the second term above.  Writing $n=mp$ this is 
$$
\sum_{p>\sqrt{x}} \frac{1}{p } \sum_{m\le x/p} \frac{\mu(m)}{m}.
$$ 
Now let $1\le k\le \sqrt{x}$ and group the primes $p$ above according to the ranges $x/(k+1) < p \le x/k$.  Thus the sum above equals
$$
\sum_{1\le k\le \sqrt{x}} M(k) \sum_{x/(k+1) <p\le x/k} \frac{1}{p}.
$$ 
Now use the asymptotics for the sum of the reciprocals of primes to see that the inner sum over $p$ above is 
$$ 
\sim \log \frac{\log (x/k)}{\log (x/(k+1))} \sim \frac{\log (1+1/k)}{\log x}. 
$$
From this the desired asymptotic follows.

The argument above is a quick sketch, and some details would need to be filled in -- but nothing too hard.  The proof follows ideas of [Dress, Iwaniec and Tenenbaum](https://eudml.org/doc/152520) and see that paper for further details in a related calculation.

Comment: Formally, one has $M(z) = - \sum_{n>z} \mu(n)/n$, so the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M(k) \log(1+\frac{1}{k})$ appears to telescope formally to $\sum_n \frac{-\mu(n) \log n}{n} = 1$.  One can presumably justify these formal computations by zeta regularization.

Comment: Excellent answer! It seems from numerical testing that @TerryTao is correct with respect to the sum $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M(k)\log(1+\frac{1}{k})=1$. A plot demonstrating this is added to the original question. I had sort of suspected $S(x)\sim 1/\log x$ from a rather hand waving heuristic (which I also have added to my posting), so it's nice to see that this actually seems to be the case.

Comment: @TerryTao: Yes indeed it is $1$.  I should have thought an epsilon more!

Comment: I don’t know whether you agree, but to me it appears that the reason behind the discrepancy between the probabilistic estimate given by Merten’s product theorem and the prime number theorem is often poorly explained in the literature. That just adding the constraint $d\leq x$ results in $S(x)\sim 1/\log x$ is—to me at least—very instructive, even though the prime number theorem itself was applied in your proof. Thanks again for a great contribution!

Comment: @Lucia You are in good company: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_constant Indeed, the numerical discrepancy that caused Legendre to be off by about 8% may in fact be related to the one in this question.

Comment: @user45947:  You're right that this is insufficiently well known.  For example, I think I should have known this, but I didn't!  One lives and learns.